# Sorting cursor made of Network Analyst outputs?

Tags: arcpy, network-analyst, cursor, sorting

I have solved OD Cost Matrix analysis and I'm trying to access the results using da.SearchCursor with SQL sorting. The problem is that the result is not sorted at all.

```
lines = arcpy.da.SearchCursor('OD_potential\Lines',['DestinationID','Total_'+impedance],None,None,False,(None,'ORDER BY DestinationID ASC'))
```

This approach works with every other layer.

Previously I used old Cursor and it worked fine, but it was much slower.

```
lines = arcpy.SearchCursor('OD_potential/Lines','','','DestinationID; Total_'+impedance,'DestinationID A')
```

I know there is a workaround using arcpy.Sort_management before the Cursor but then the runtime is same as using the old Cursor.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check examples 5A and 5B in the [online help](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/SearchCursor/018w00000011000000/): use the sort method or 'ORDER BY' without 'ASC'.

Comment: Thanks. If I get it right, arcpy.da cursors are sortable only when applied on database layer. I've used python sorted method instead and it works.